# How to return image url using multer

Tags: node.js, file-upload, mean-stack, multer, image-upload

I just started with node. I want to upload the image to the server, I am using multer for an image upload. I am using below code and I am able to upload the images to the server, but not able to send the image url back to the client as success response. Any help will be appreciated.

```
var request = require('request');
var app = require('../app');
var util = require('../response_util');
var multer  =   require('multer');
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, 'public/upload');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    var imageUrl = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now()+'.jpg';
    callback(null, imageUrl);
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).single('image');

app.get('/img/home',function(req,res){
    res.send("welcome to image home");
});

app.post('/img/upload',function(req,res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err,result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file."+err);
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded url : "+result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
app.post('/img/upload',function(req,res) {
upload(req,res,function(err,result) {
console.log(err);
console.log(result);
    if(err) {
        return res.end("Error uploading file."+err);
    }
    var path = req.file.path;
    res.end("File is uploaded url : " + path);
});
```

You can take path of uploaded file using req.file.path object in multer. this is working for me.

Comment: Not working for me, req.file returns undefined

Comment: have you created upload method correctly?

Comment: This solution worked for me. You can concatenate `file.path` with the `base_url` and return.